# combine different row data into one cell in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a view with the following structure:

```
areas    employee_id     complaint_type_id
a1        e1                c1
a2        e1                c1
a3        e2                c1
a1        e1                c2
.
```

Now in the code, I am fetching `area` and `complaint_type_id` for a particular employee from view. I want to display the complaint categories assigned to an employee for different areas.

The output I am getting is as follows:

```
area       complaint_type_id
a1          c1
a2          c1
a3          c1
a1          c2
a2          c2
a3          c2
```

In this output, the areas are getting repeat for each kind of complaint id. I want to display complaint categories in a single row for a particular area

My desired output is as follows:

```
area          complaint_type_id
a1            c1,c2
a2            c1,c2
a3            c1,c2
```

I tried using the `group by` clause but in the output of the `group by` areas are appearing twice for each complaint type. How can I achieve my desired output?

Comment: use FOR XML PATH  listagg equivalent!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take CTEs for other tables and this will work:

```
select distinct t1.area,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + t2.complaint_type_id
         from Table1 t2
         where t1.area = t2.area
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'') data
from Table1 t1;
```

check:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0f121/7

Comment: your solution is working for me but it is fetching all type of complaint_type_id. I need only those  which are assigned to a particular employee

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent version of SQLS or SQLAzure:

```
SELECT
  area,
  STRING_AGG(complaint_type_id, ',') as complaint_type_id
FROM
  table
GROUP BY 
  area
```

ps; interesting article: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation - the precis of which is "if you dont have a recent nough version of SQLS to have STRING_AGG, use STUFF/FOR XML PATH or the .NET CLR"